# How to launch a cocos2D game from single view app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I created a regular simple iOS app (a single view application) with one button and I want to launch a cocos2D game from the iOS app. In other words, I want to launch the cocos2D game when I press on the button from my myapp.xib. I don't want to use URL schemes to launch the game because that will require the user to download my app as well as download the game. I want the user to be able to launch the game from my app internally. This is the game I want to launch from my app:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/14439/how-to-make-a-game-like-fruit-ninja-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-part-3

I was able to successfully add this game as a dependency in my xcode project. However, I'm not sure how to go about launching the game from app.

Here's some ideas that I had, but they didn't really work for me.
Is there any way I can:

- Call the app delegate of the game (not the app delegate of my app) from the IBAction in my app to launch the game?
- Call the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of the game (not the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of my app) from the IBAction in my app to launch the game?
- Call the main.m file of the game (not the main.m of my app) from the IBAction in my app to launch the game?

From what I understand, these are three different ways of launching an iOS app. Keep in mind that I am developing an app (not a game) that will allow a user to launch the game above internally through the app. Ideally, it would nice (and also easy) if I can simply do a pushviewcontroller from my app to the game, but I'm not sure if there is an easy way to approach this.

Is there anyway I can launch this game internally through my app? Any advice, suggestions, sample source code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **YES**

You would need to have just one `AppDelegate` (the one of your iOS app), and move there all the `cocos2D` init stuff. Then, you can launch the game from your `IBAction` with something like this.-

```
CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
[director pushScene:[YourFirstGameScene node]]; 
[director resume];
[self presentModalViewController:director animated:YES];
```

Please, take next snippet as an example to init/end `cocos2d` from your `appDelegate`

```
- (void) initCocos {
    // Create an CCGLView with a RGB565 color buffer, and a depth buffer of 0-bits
    CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[self.window bounds]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8    //kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                   depthFormat:0    //GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES
                            preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                    sharegroup:nil
                                 multiSampling:NO
                               numberOfSamples:0];

    self.director = (CCDirectorIOS*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    self.director.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    // Display FSP and SPF
    [self.director setDisplayStats:NO];

    // set FPS at 60
    [self.director setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];

    // attach the openglView to the director
    [self.director setView:glView];

    // for rotation and other messages
    [self.director setDelegate:self];

    // 2D projection
    [self.director setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];
    //  [director setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection3D];

    // Enables High Res mode (Retina Display) on iPhone 4 and maintains low res on all other devices
    if( ! [self.director enableRetinaDisplay:NO] )
        CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");

    // Default texture format for PNG/BMP/TIFF/JPEG/GIF images
    // It can be RGBA8888, RGBA4444, RGB5_A1, RGB565
    // You can change anytime.
    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

    // When in iPhone RetinaDisplay, iPad, iPad RetinaDisplay mode, CCFileUtils will append the "-hd", "-ipad", "-ipadhd" to all loaded files
    // If the -hd, -ipad, -ipadhd files are not found, it will load the non-suffixed version
    //[CCFileUtils setiPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-hd"];        // Default on iPhone RetinaDisplay is "-hd"
    [CCFileUtils setiPadSuffix:@""];                    // Default on iPad is "" (empty string)
    //[CCFileUtils setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-ipadhd"];  // Default on iPad RetinaDisplay is "-ipadhd"

    // Assume that PVR images have premultiplied alpha
    [CCTexture2D PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha:YES];
}

- (void) endCocos {
    CC_DIRECTOR_END();
    self.director = nil;
}
```

Actually, what I do is a call to `initCocos` just before pushing my `director`, and `endCocos` just after closing the game, like

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[appDelegate endCocos];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey ssantos, can you specify what you mean by "cocos2d init" stuff. Is that the code in:

-The game's app delegate?
-"YourFirstGameScene".mm?

Comment: I mean the initialization code on game's delegate, as scenes inits should stay where they are. I'm updating my answer with an example

Comment: So far, I tried to link the libs. So that works. However, I crash whenever I press the button. This is the error that I get. I had to make the YourFirstGameScene as a @class in order to get the app to run.  ** Assertion failure in -[CCDirectorDisplayLink pushScene:]*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Argument must be non-nil

Comment: Well, it seems that you're passing `nil` to `pushScene`. Could you trace the value you're passing?

Comment: Yeah. my created class leads to the YourFirstGameScene. I also have it allocated and initialized.

Comment: Mmh it's hard to tell without debugging, but there's a nil object somewhere. Please, debug step by step (inside `pushScene` method) until you reach exactly the line that's throwing the exception.

Comment: I now got this error, which is the same. I found the line of where this code is. *** Assertion failure in -[HelloWorldLayer addChild:z:]

Comment: Have you checked the param for `addChild` isn't nil?

Comment: Yes, It's a CCNode and z contains an integer.

Comment: Ok, I run out of ideas... http://img.desmotivaciones.es/201106/Futurama_Fry_Looking_Squint.jpg

Comment: Anyway, if you could post some relevant code in your question (including the snippet where you actually create your game scene, and its init method), I'll give it another try tomorrow.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28522/discussion-between-kofi-and-ssantos)